# Smart Loop List Creation in Python for Django Choice fields

Tags: python, django

So.  The following isn't very 'smart' ;)

```
MONTHS = (
    ('Jan', 'Jan'),
    ('Feb', 'Feb'),
    ('Mar', 'Mar'),
    ('Apr', 'Apr'),
    ('May', 'May'),
    ('Jun', 'Jun'),
    ('Jul', 'Jul'),
    ('Aug', 'Aug'),
    ('Sep', 'Sep'),
    ('Oct', 'Oct'),
    ('Nov', 'Nov'),
    ('Dec', 'Dec'),
)

YEARS = (
    ('1995', '1995'),
    ('1996', '1996'),
    ('1997', '1997'),
    ('1998', '1998'),
    ('1999', '1999'),
    ('2000', '2000'),
    ('2001', '2001'),
    ('2002', '2002'),
    ('2003', '2003'),
    ('2004', '2004'),
    ('2005', '2005'),
    ('2006', '2006'),
    ('2007', '2007'),
    ('2008', '2008'),
    ('2009', '2009'),
    ('2010', '2010'),
)
```

I'm newer to python, and would love to produce stuff like this 'pythonically'.

Such as,

- a list of year tuples from 1995 to current year.
- a list of the abbreviated months of the year

Thanks Stackers'

Comment: Perhaps the question is how to produce lists like this, with 'for loops' I suppose.

Comment: Btw. why are you using tuples consisting of two identical values?

Comment: @ecik: That's how django's choices works in forms/models. See http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/choices/. The first item in the tuple is the actual value, and the second is what gets displayed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
In [17]: from datetime import datetime

In [18]: tuple((str(n), str(n)) for n in range(1995, datetime.now().year + 1))
Out[18]:
(('1995', '1995'),
 ('1996', '1996'),
 ('1997', '1997'),
 ('1998', '1998'),
 ('1999', '1999'),
 ('2000', '2000'),
 ('2001', '2001'),
 ('2002', '2002'),
 ('2003', '2003'),
 ('2004', '2004'),
 ('2005', '2005'),
 ('2006', '2006'),
 ('2007', '2007'),
 ('2008', '2008'),
 ('2009', '2009'),
 ('2010', '2010'))

In [19]: import calendar

In [20]: tuple((m, m) for m in calendar.month_abbr[1:])
Out[20]:
(('Jan', 'Jan'),
 ('Feb', 'Feb'),
 ('Mar', 'Mar'),
 ('Apr', 'Apr'),
 ('May', 'May'),
 ('Jun', 'Jun'),
 ('Jul', 'Jul'),
 ('Aug', 'Aug'),
 ('Sep', 'Sep'),
 ('Oct', 'Oct'),
 ('Nov', 'Nov'),
 ('Dec', 'Dec'))
```

Comment: Calendar module also provides an attribute called month_abbr which is probably more suitable here.

Comment: To get the current year you should do `import datetime; datetime.datetime.now().year + 1` as the second arg of the range.

Answer (score 8):

Try using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to make a list of two-tuples.

```
MONTHS = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
somemonth = models.TextField(max_length=3, choices=zip(MONTHS,MONTHS))
```

`choices` will be set to `[('Jan', 'Jan'), ('Feb', 'Feb'), ...]`.

---

In response to the comments on this answer, the "tuple" list comprehension version would be:

```
tuple((m, m) for m in MONTHS)
```

Versus the zip version:

```
tuple(zip(MONTHS, MONTHS))
```

But strictly speaking, Django doesn't need a tuple of choices, so:

```
zip(MONTHS, MONTHS)
```

Comment: Hey I like the 'zip()' method... but using the tuple() seems much less work!

Comment: @Daryl I've updated the answer to compare the list comprehension to `zip()`.

Answer (score 3):

See [module time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html).

```
>>> import time
```

For the months we can use `strptime` to turn a month number 1-12 into a `struct_time`, and then use `strftime` to pull the month name out.

```
>>> [time.strftime('%b', time.strptime(str(i), '%m')) for i in range(1, 13)]
['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

The years are more straightforward, we just need to know the current year (plus one, due to the way `range` works).

```
>>> [str(i) for i in range(1995, time.localtime().tm_year + 1)]
['1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010']
```

I added `str(i)` to have the years returned as strings since that's the way you wrote them. If integers are okay then you can drop the whole list comprehension and simply use `range(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils.dates import MONTHS


class MyCoolModel(models.Model):
    YEARS = YEARS = [(i,)*2 for i in range(1995, datetime.today().year + 1)]

    month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=MONTHS.items())
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=YEARS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although some of the other answers might be "smarter", I dislike the idea of using a loop to define a tuple. Perhaps the following is a more readable compromise :

```
MONTHS = (
    ('Jan',) * 2,
    ('Feb',) * 2,
    ('Mar',) * 2,
    ('Apr',) * 2,
    ('May',) * 2,
    ('Jun',) * 2,
    ('Jul',) * 2,
    ('Aug',) * 2,
    ('Sep',) * 2,
    ('Oct',) * 2,
    ('Nov',) * 2,
    ('Dec',) * 2,
)

YEARS = (
    ('1995',) * 2,
    ('1996',) * 2,
    ('1997',) * 2,
    ('1998',) * 2,
    ('1999',) * 2,
    ('2000',) * 2,
    ('2001',) * 2,
    ('2002',) * 2,
    ('2003',) * 2,
    ('2004',) * 2,
    ('2005',) * 2,
    ('2006',) * 2,
    ('2007',) * 2,
    ('2008',) * 2,
    ('2009',) * 2,
    ('2010',) * 2,
)
```

Comment: why don't you like using a comprehension to define a tuple?

Comment: Personally, for constants, I rather be more verbose and stick to tuples as oppose to defining a list with list comprehensions. It's more for personal taste and readability than anything else.