# How to properly use the "choices" field option in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, enums

I'm reading the tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#choices
and i'm trying to create a box where the user can select the month he was born in. What I tried was

```
 MONTH_CHOICES = (
    (JANUARY, "January"),
    (FEBRUARY, "February"),
    (MARCH, "March"),
    ....
    (DECEMBER, "December"),
)

month = CharField(max_length=9,
                  choices=MONTHS_CHOICES,
                  default=JANUARY)
```

Is this correct? I see that in the tutorial I was reading, they for some reason created variables first, like so

```
FRESHMAN = 'FR'
SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
JUNIOR = 'JR'
SENIOR = 'SR'
```

Why did they create those variables? Also, the MONTHS_CHOICES is in a model called People, so would the code I provided create a "Months Choices) column in the database called called "People" and would it say what month the user was born in after he clicks on of the months and submits the form?

Comment: Add this point I suggest you look into [Django-Choices](https://github.com/bigjason/django-choices) package.

Comment: The link is broken, here is the most recent docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices

Answer (score 68, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices):

> Field.choices
>
> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of
>   iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as
>   choices for this field. If this is given, the default form widget will
>   be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field.
>
> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be stored, and
>   the second element is the human-readable name.

So, your code is correct, except that you should either define variables `JANUARY`, `FEBRUARY` etc. or use `calendar` module to define `MONTH_CHOICES`:

```
import calendar
...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    MONTH_CHOICES = [(str(i), calendar.month_name[i]) for i in range(1,13)]

    month = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=MONTH_CHOICES, default='1')
```

Answer (score 232):

I think no one actually has answered to the first question:

> Why did they create those variables?

Those variables aren't strictly necessary. It's true. You can perfectly do something like this:

```
MONTH_CHOICES = (
    ("JANUARY", "January"),
    ("FEBRUARY", "February"),
    ("MARCH", "March"),
    # ....
    ("DECEMBER", "December"),
)

month = models.CharField(max_length=9,
                  choices=MONTH_CHOICES,
                  default="JANUARY")
```

Why using variables is better? Error prevention and logic separation.

```
JAN = "JANUARY"
FEB = "FEBRUARY"
MAR = "MAR"
# (...)

MONTH_CHOICES = (
    (JAN, "January"),
    (FEB, "February"),
    (MAR, "March"),
    # ....
    (DEC, "December"),
)
```

Now, imagine you have a view where you create a new Model instance. Instead of doing this:

```
new_instance = MyModel(month='JANUARY')
```

You'll do this:

```
new_instance = MyModel(month=MyModel.JAN)
```

In the first option you are hardcoding the value. If there is a set of values you can input, you should limit those options when coding.
Also, if you eventually need to change the code at the Model layer, now you don't need to make any change in the Views layer.

Comment: You should seriously consider namespacing variables you use for choices in Django model fields; it should be apparent that the variable is related to a specific field in order to avoid confusing future programmers who could add similar choice fields to the model. In python 3, I use an IntEnum class for this and I name it in a way that makes it obvious which model field it relates to.

Comment: Starting from python3.8 it could be more convenient to declare variables just inside declaring `MONTH_CHOICES`, like `MONTH_CHOICES = ((JAN := "JANUARY", "January")...)`.

Answer (score 152):

For Django3.0+, use `models.TextChoices` (see [docs-v3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) for **enumeration types**)

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Month(models.TextChoices):
        JAN = "1", "JANUARY"
        FEB = "2", "FEBRUARY"
        MAR = "3", "MAR"
        # (...)

    month = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Month.choices,
        default=Month.JAN
    )
```

Usage::

```py
>>> obj = MyModel.objects.create(month='1')
>>> assert obj.month == obj.Month.JAN == '1'
>>> assert MyModel.Month(obj.month) is obj.Month.JAN
>>> assert MyModel.Month(obj.month).value is '1'
>>> assert MyModel.Month(obj.month).label == 'JANUARY'
>>> assert MyModel.Month(obj.month).name == 'JAN'
>>> assert MyModel.objects.filter(month=MyModel.Month.JAN).count() >= 1

>>> obj2 = MyModel(month=MyModel.Month.FEB)
>>> assert obj2.get_month_display() == obj2.Month(obj2.month).label
```

Let's say we known the label is 'JANUARY', how to get the name 'JAN' and the value '1'?

```py
label = "JANUARY"
name = {i.label: i.name for i in MyModel.Month}[label]
print(repr(name))  # 'JAN'
value = {i.label: i.value for i in MyModel.Month}[label]
print(repr(value))  # '1'
```

Personally, I would rather use `models.IntegerChoices`

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Month(models.IntegerChoices):
        JAN = 1, "JANUARY"
        FEB = 2, "FEBRUARY"
        MAR = 3, "MAR"
        # (...)

    month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=Month.choices,
        default=Month.JAN
    )
```

Comment: This is a good solution for more recent versions of Django - with the added benefit that `TextChoices` can also be defined as a main class and shared across models. Good choice for never changing data.

Comment: Note that you can simply use `JANUARY = 1`, `FEBRUARY = 2`, etc. without specifying the label and Django is smart enough to produce 'January', 'February', etc. from that in the choice option list.

Answer (score 17):

### Jan, 2023 Update:

The new way is using [models.TextChoices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) as shown below which is **built-in** so you don't need to install any packages. *The 1st value is the actual value and the 2nd value is displayed on Django Admin:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

    class Months(models.TextChoices):
     # Actual value ↓      # ↓ Displayed on Django Admin  
        JANUARY = 'JAN', 'January'
        FEBRUARY = 'FEB', 'February'
        MARCH = 'MAR', 'March'
        APRIL = 'APR', 'April'
        MAY = 'MAY', 'May'

    month = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=Months.choices,
        default=Months.APRIL 
    )

    class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
     # Actual value ↓      # ↓ Displayed on Django Admin
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', 'Freshman'
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', 'Sophomore'
        JUNIOR = 'JR', 'Junior'
        SENIOR = 'SR', 'Senior'
        GRADUATE = 'GR', 'Graduate'

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.SOPHOMORE,
    )
```

I also rewrote the code above in the old way which is also **built-in**.

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
              # ↓ Actual value
    JANUARY = 'JAN'
    FEBRUARY = 'FEB'
    MARCH = 'MAR'
    APRIL = 'APR'
    MAY = 'MAY'

    MONTHS = [      # ↓ Displayed on Django Admin
        (JANUARY, 'January'),
        (FEBRUARY, 'February'),
        (MARCH, 'March'),
        (APRIL, 'April'),
        (MAY, 'May'),
    ]

    month = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=MONTHS,
        default=APRIL # Or "default=MONTHS[3]"
    )
              # ↓ Actual value
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'

    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
                     # ↓ Displayed on Django Admin
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    ]

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=SOPHOMORE # Or "default=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES[1]"
    )
```

Comment: is there a specific reason to nest those classes?

Comment: What is the purpose of using enumerations in this case?

Answer (score 13):

The cleanest solution is to use the `django-model-utils` library:

```
from model_utils import Choices

class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS = Choices('draft', 'published')
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, default=STATUS.draft, max_length=20)
```

https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#choices

Comment: Hmm..I am personally not comfortable in installing a library for such a simple task. look at @Waket Zheng's answer

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest to use [django-model-utils](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils) instead of Django built-in solution. 
The main advantage of this solution is the lack of string declaration duplication. All choice items are declared exactly once. Also this is the easiest way for declaring choices using 3 values and storing database value different than usage in source code.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from model_utils import Choices

class MyModel(models.Model):
   MONTH = Choices(
       ('JAN', _('January')),
       ('FEB', _('February')),
       ('MAR', _('March')),
   )
   # [..]
   month = models.CharField(
       max_length=3,
       choices=MONTH,
       default=MONTH.JAN,
   )
```

And with usage IntegerField instead:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from model_utils import Choices

class MyModel(models.Model):
   MONTH = Choices(
       (1, 'JAN', _('January')),
       (2, 'FEB', _('February')),
       (3, 'MAR', _('March')),
   )
   # [..]
   month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
       choices=MONTH,
       default=MONTH.JAN,
   )
```

- This method has one small disadvantage: in any IDE (eg. PyCharm) there will be no code completion for available choices (it’s because those values aren’t standard members of Choices class).

Answer (score 4):

You can't have bare words in the code, that's the reason why they created variables (your code will fail with `NameError`).

The code you provided would create a database table named `month` (plus whatever prefix django adds to that), because that's the name of the `CharField`.

But there are better ways to create the particular choices you want. See [a previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809856/smart-loop-list-creation-in-python-for-django-choice-fields).

```
import calendar
tuple((m, m) for m in calendar.month_name[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

### $ pip install django-better-choices

For those who are interested, I have created [`django-better-choices`](https://github.com/lokhman/django-better-choices) library, that provides a nice interface to work with Django choices for Python 3.7+. It supports custom parameters, lots of useful features and is very IDE friendly.

You can define your choices as a class:

```py
from django_better_choices import Choices


class PAGE_STATUS(Choices):
    CREATED = 'Created'
    PENDING = Choices.Value('Pending', help_text='This set status to pending')
    ON_HOLD = Choices.Value('On Hold', value='custom_on_hold')

    VALID = Choices.Subset('CREATED', 'ON_HOLD')

    class INTERNAL_STATUS(Choices):
        REVIEW = 'On Review'

    @classmethod
    def get_help_text(cls):
        return tuple(
            value.help_text
            for value in cls.values()
            if hasattr(value, 'help_text')
        )
```

Then do the following operations and **much much more**:

```py
print( PAGE_STATUS.CREATED )                # 'created'
print( PAGE_STATUS.ON_HOLD )                # 'custom_on_hold'
print( PAGE_STATUS.PENDING.display )        # 'Pending'
print( PAGE_STATUS.PENDING.help_text )      # 'This set status to pending'

'custom_on_hold' in PAGE_STATUS.VALID       # True
PAGE_STATUS.CREATED in PAGE_STATUS.VALID    # True

PAGE_STATUS.extract('CREATED', 'ON_HOLD')   # ~= PAGE_STATUS.VALID

for value, display in PAGE_STATUS:
    print( value, display )

PAGE_STATUS.get_help_text()
PAGE_STATUS.VALID.get_help_text()
```

And of course, it is fully supported by Django and Django Migrations:

```py
class Page(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(choices=PAGE_STATUS, default=PAGE_STATUS.CREATED)
```

Full documentation here: https://pypi.org/project/django-better-choices/

Comment: Sorry but I still find this a useful duplication: "CREATED = 'Created'"