# Understanding "(item, item) for item in ..."

Tags: python

In my code I have following line:

```
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())
```

And I just can't understand why there is `(item, item) for ...` instead for example `item for ...`

This code snippet is from http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#creating-a-model-to-work-with

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide sample IN/OUT for your particular problem.

Comment: I gave you whole code.

Comment: What precisely don't you understand? The syntax? `item for ...` would give you a sorted list of items. `(item, item) for ...` gives you a sorted list of *two-tuples*, where both values in each tuple are the same.

Comment: So why I need a sorted list of two-tuples instead sorted list of one-tuple?

Comment: The first version isn't a sorted list of one-tuples, that would be `(item,) for ...`. As to why you need two-tuples: presumably, that's what the API of the library you're using requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676156/how-to-properly-use-the-choices-field-option-in-django).

It's looks like you need a collection of tuples `(value, label)` as chooses for the `CharField` model. In your case, the value and the label are the same.