# how to make ' add choice in admin panel ' see description

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i want add an '+ or add' inside add new record

i mean when i add new record in `admin panel` and i have name box and i want add many names when click on + or add how to do that

model.py :

```
class Android(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

i tried add many name field but it's not what i want ,, i tried something like that

```
   class Android(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")

        def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: are you looking for choices?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676156/how-to-properly-use-the-choices-field-option-in-django

Comment: no , i want add ' + ' in each field like name , title ... to add more name in same record