# Can multiple values be assigned to one variable without brackets "[]" or parentheses "()" (Python)

Tags: python, list, tuples, parentheses, brackets

From [**this django answer in SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676156/how-to-properly-use-the-choices-field-option-in-django/59199143#59199143), I found **3 variables "JAN", "FEB" and "MAR"** in **the class "Month"** extending **"models.TextChoices"** as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Month(models.TextChoices):
        JAN = "1", "JANUARY"  # Here
        FEB = "2", "FEBRUARY" # Here
        MAR = "3", "MAR"      # Here
        # (...)

    month = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Month.choices,
        default=Month.JAN
    )
```

And multiple values are assigned to each variable without **brackets "[]" which creates List** or **parentheses "()" which creates Tuple** as shown below:

```py
JAN = "1", "JANUARY"
FEB = "2", "FEBRUARY"
MAR = "3", "MAR"
```

Now, can multiple values be assigned to one variable without **brackets "[]"** or **parentheses "()"** in **Python**?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, multiple values can be assigned to one variable without **brackets "[]"** or **parentheses "()"**.

And these below are actually **Tuple**:

```py
JAN = "1", "JANUARY"
FEB = "2", "FEBRUARY"
MAR = "3", "MAR"
```

So, in **Python**, you can create **Tuple** without **parentheses "()"**.

For example, these below are **Tuple**:

```py
fruits = "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"
```

```py
fruits = "Apple",
```

In addition, this below without a trailing comma is not **Tuple**. This below is **String type**:

```py
fruits = "Apple"
```